# c++ 2 pointers to same object

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm wondering if I have 2 pointers pointing same object, and then I delete it using pointer 1, will it still be in memory and pointer 2 will point null, or object will stay in memory and I need to use delete pointer 2 to free it?

I mean:

```
int *p1, *p2;
p1=new int;
p2=p1;
*p1=5;
p2=p1;
delete p1;

int x=*p2;
//Error or x=5?
```

Comment: You don't assign anything to `p2` anywhere.

Comment: In your example, you don't give p2 a value, so it won't be the same as p1! Other than that, Lightness Races in Orbit is spot on. Oh, but as to the question in the code: you might get an error, or you might not get an error. It's UB.

Comment: I already upvoted your answer. Don't push it! ;)

Comment: @MrLister: I'll wait until your vote is locked-in :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The object will be *gone*.
- Pointer 2 will not be a null pointer, but a *dangling* pointer, with its previous but now-invalid value; doing anything with it will be an error.<sup>1</sup>
- That's exactly true for pointer 1, too. There will be no difference between the two.

---

<sup>1 - Well, UB, not an "error" per se. But don't do it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's generally good not to have two pointers pointing to the same memory. That's because if you delete one, the other will be a dangling pointer.

Anything you do with the memory after deleting it is **undefined behavior**.

In your case ( I assume you forgot to do `p2=p1`, as your question suggests ), `int x=*p2;` is undefined, since the memory `p2` points to was deleted.

Comment: The memory's still there, but the object ain't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hope he got my point (I know you did). Obviously your RAM isn't going to go anywhere :)

Comment: I suppose it could be beamed out in-place

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yeah, but the bad thing is that it's entirely possible that the memory still contains the value it did, AND that it's still reachable by the pointer, so it LOOKS like it works!

Comment: @MrLister not only possible, but probable. That's why I said he shouldn't do it.

Comment: How probably depends on the situation. For instance, when you're running in DEBUG mode with MS Visual C++, deleting a pointer also overwrites the memory it points to with 0xFEEEFEEE. So if you're debugging thoroughly enough, you will discover your bug!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes - "the memory p2 points to was deleted"

Comment: Yes, as opposed to "deleting a pointer" (which is what @MrLister said)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, I've never heard the C++ statement `delete ptr;` being referred to as "deleting a pointee". If I were to start saying that, it would raise eyebrows!

Comment: @MrLister: If you were to call it "deleting a pointer", unless `ptr` were of a type `T**` you'd be _wrong_.

Comment: I too always say "delete the pointer", even though **I know** it's not the pointer that's deleted.